# 2D matrix value difference

Tags: python, excel, matrix

I have 2 columns in excel, parameter `A1`:`A5` and value `D1`:`D5`:

```
1    2.0
2    1.5
3    3.5
4    2.3
5    7.7
```

Please let me know how to create a 2D matrix using iPython notebook. For both rows and columns the parameter (column A) should be used, and the cells should have the difference of the values. E.g.:

```
    1   2   3  
1   0.0 0.5 -1.5
2  -0.5 0.0 -2.0
3   1.5 2.0 0.0
```

Or can be just one sided matrix.

Or if this is easier to do with excel, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using one of the scientific python distributions, see scipy.org, Install section. I use Anaconda.
If you use the IPython notebook installed from one of the scientific python distributions, then you are ready to use it right away.

You get many useful packages, specifically, pandas package.

You do

```
import pandas as pd
```

then

```
data = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

you get a data frame, with all the data.
You can set the data frame column names by supplying a list of names with the keyword argument 'names' in the above function.

See here: [pd.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)